# Guardar una tabla en un archivo .txt

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa donde debo de ingresar los datos de varios productos (nombre, precio unitario, iva, etc.). En cualquier momento el usuario puede ver los datos de los productos que ha ingresado y cuando estos se muestran deben de estar ordenados en forma de tabla (imagen), hasta ahí todo va bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que antes de cerrar el programa se deben de guardar los datos de los productos dentro de un archivo de texto (.txt), quiero guardarlos en forma de tabla igual que en la imagen pero no se como hacerle para que se guarde respetando las filas y columnas.

En el programa utilice la funcion gotoxy para imprimir la tabla.

Para imprimirla en el archivo de texto intente con la funcion seekp pero esta solo me respeta las columnas, cuando le digo que salte a la siguiente fila para imprimir los datos del siguiente producto no lo hace, los datos se transcriben uno sobre otro en la misma fila y sobre texto ya existente.

Asi se ve cuando guardo el archivo de texto pero sin datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así se ve cuando lo guardo con datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte del código que utilizo para el archivo de texto

```
void archivo_txt()
{
    ofstream archivo;
    archivo.open("c://Guardado//texto_save.txt", ios::out);
    archivo << endl;
    archivo << "Lista de ordenes generadas";
    archivo << endl;
    archivo << " Numero de orden |    Nombre de producto    | Codigo |  Cantidad  |  Precio unitario   | Subtotal |    IVA    | Precio total |";
    archivo<<endl;
    
    for (int h = 1; h < k;h++)
    {
        archivo << endl;
        archivo.seekp(8);
        archivo << producto[h].numor;
        archivo.seekp(20);
        archivo << producto[h].descr;
        archivo.seekp(46);
        archivo << producto[h].codigo;
        archivo.seekp(58);
        archivo << producto[h].cant;
        archivo.seekp(72);
        archivo << "$" << producto[h].preuni;
        archivo.seekp(89);
        archivo << "$" << producto[h].subt;
        archivo.seekp(100);
        archivo << "$" << producto[h].IVA;
        archivo.seekp(112);
        archivo << "$" << producto[h].total;
    }
    archivo.close();
}
```

Saben como puedo hacerle o que puedo usar para que se guarde como quiero? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! c o c++??? son dos lenguajes distintos...

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
archivo.open("c://Guardado//texto_save.txt", ios::out);
                                                  ^- AQUÍ
```

El segundo argumento es de tipo [`std::ios_base::openmode`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode), que, entre otros, admite los siguientes valores:

> **ios::out**
> Sobreescribe el contenido anterior del archivo.
> **ios::app**
> Todas las escrituras se realizan **al final** del archivo.
> **ios::ate**
> El puntero se posiciona **al final** del archivo al abrirlo.

En tu caso, bastaría con utilizar el último valor:

```
archivo.open( "c://Guardado//texto_save.txt", ios::ate );
```